# Angular js http get fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter

My Angular Js app fails when im trying to fetch json data from my web server ( made with codeigniter ). Other urls which respond with json data works fine but mine some how doesn't.

Angular js code:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://appbackend.wrappic.nl/')
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
        console.log("Error");
    });
});
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You sure this isn't a cross domain issue?

Comment: What is the error  you get? It is probably caused by your webserver

Comment: How can I check if it is a cross domain issue? As far I can see the webserver doesn't respond with an error..

Comment: Open your console, trigger the request and see what errors is produced under "Network"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works on other servers, but not your own, I think that you miss a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

Try adding the header at the top of your PHP page like such:

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```